# assign value to struct variables in C

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem assigning values to variable in struct. My code is shown below.

```
typedef struct _neuron
{
    double value[100];
    int id;
}NEURON;

int main() {
  NEURON node;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    node.value[i] = 10;
    printf("the value is %d\n",node.value[i]);
  }
}
```

The values I assigned to struct variables are 10, but I am getting 0 instead of 10. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: turn up the warning level in your compiler

Comment: or more likely - dont ignore warnings from yr compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier to `printf`.

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int` argument, but you're passing in a `double`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

For a `double`, use the `%f` format specifier.

```
printf("the value is %f\n",node.value[i]);
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted, if it answers your question.

Comment: @StephanLechner Not for `printf`.  For `scanf`, you use `%lf` for a `double *` and `%f` for a `float *`.